# Dynamically added input not included in form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've got something similar to

`<form action="/insert" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name = "input_data"/>
<input type="text" class="hidden form-control" id = "hidden_template" name ="input_data"/>
<button type="button"  class="add input">Add Input</button>
</form>`

When the user clicks the button with class 'add input', I clone the hidden input with the hidden_template ID, and then I remove the class hidden on the new element and append it to the HTML. I do this in jQuery and it works great.

However, when I enter text in the new element and then submit the form, it's not included in the POST.

Is there anything I need to do to make sure the form will included the newly appended input in its submission?

Comment: How does your JavaScript look like?

Comment: Please add javascript code as well

Answer (score 0):

Your cloned element has the same name as the original so its value replaces the original in the POST.

Change your input to:

`<input type="text" class="hidden form-control" name ="input_data[]"/>`

Note the `input_data[]` this will create an array on the server side with each value in its proper index.

Also, IDs must be unique, so you do not want to have an ID on the element you are going to clone, otherwise all of the clones will have the same ID which would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you can explicit the link between `form` and `input` tags by adding a `form` attribute to `input` :

```
<input ... form="form-id">
```